# iText not working outside netbeans

Tags: java, itext

I wrote the following code in Netbeans editor in Java UI application for generating PDF using itext.

```
    String result="";
    Document doc=new Document();
    PdfWriter writer=null;
    DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    try
    {
        writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File("second.pdf")));
        doc.addAuthor("abcdefg");
        doc.addCreationDate();
        doc.addProducer();
        doc.addCreator("abcdefg");
        doc.addTitle("Invoice for company");
        doc.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        doc.open();
        doc.newPage();

        doc.add(new Paragraph("new paragraph"));

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell cellValue = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header 1"));
        cellValue.setColspan(1);

       table.addCell(cellValue);
        doc.add(table);
        result= "Successfully created preview.Please check the document";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       result= "Doucment already opened. Please close it";
        System.out.println("exception came");
    }
    finally
    {
        if(doc!=null)
        {
            doc.close();
        }
        if(writer!=null)
        {
            writer.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This same piece of code is generating the pdf when I hit the RUN button in NetBeans but if double click the ".JAR" file in the project folder it is not able to add table to the pdf and generating the exception IOException Document has no pages.

There are two interesting things happening here :

1) When I remove the table adding part from my code, it is working very fine in in both the cases. This proves that "build" in netbeans is happening properly.

2) When I add the table part. The exception is generated but it is not executing the catch block and finally block. I am saying this because if catch and finally blocks are executed properly DOCUMENT will be definitely closed properly. But here when I double click the document when my app generated the file, it is showing that the FILE IS ALREADY IN USE AND IT IS DAMAGED FILE. This proves that the catch and finally blocks are not executing.

Comment: Can you post the complete code. When you create Document.
Are you opening and closing document properly?

Comment: Does the jar contain your recent code changes? Do you have to rebuild it?

Comment: hello andy,

The build is done properly, I am sure about it because when i remove the table part from my code pdf file is generating with paragraph "new paragraph" , but when i add the table part the code is running in Netbeans but not in direct execution of jar file.

Comment: Did you solve this?